# Live audio production as well?

Tags: discussion, scope

Reading the definition of the site, it seems very focused.  I'd like to propose that we allow questions regarding live sound as well.  While it doesn't have to be the focus of the site, I'd hate to leave those questions and answers out, as there is a lot of overlap.

To clarify what I have in mind, I'd like to include questions about live mixing, speaker placement, mic-ing techniques, etc.

Thoughts?  Will this be allowed here?  I certainly hope so.

Comment: I hope so to, even if the live sound is not being recorded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my mind these are definitely on-topic.  There's already 4 questions tagged [live](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live), and all have been answered and received at least 2 upvotes.

Comment: Ben Versluis, is that you?

Comment: @Brad: Nope, sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Ah, no worries.  I'm also in Illinois, and thought you were a friend of mine.

Comment: +1 for a "totally agreed".

Comment: I'm glad to hear this; I'll be using this site a lot more if I can ask live audio questions.